# What to choose ThreadPoolTaskExecutor or SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor in my case?

Tags: spring

I am working on a existing Application which has got this piece of code

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="50" />
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
      <property name="queueCapacity" value="250" />
   </bean>
```

We have a method , which is using the above taskExecutor to complete a particuar task .
(This task should be completed , but can be completed asycnchronsly )

This particular  task is actually  responsible to insert 100 documents into Database .

So i was planning to use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` .

Please let me know if this will impact performance or  create any issues

Our Application is a multithreaded one , and there will be aprox 700 users at any time .

So i dont know how it behaves under production environment (which may be fine during development )

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the usage of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor does make sense in cases, if you want to execute some long-time-executing tasks, e.g. if you want to compress log files at the end of a day. In other cases, if you want to execute a short-time-executing task every n seconds or minutes, you should use the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, because of reusing of system resources.

Technically both variants will work. But I would use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for your task.